# Change TextInputLayout error font?

Tags: android, fonts, android-textinputlayout

Is it possible to change the TextInputLayout error text font for an EditText?

I could only change the color or text size, via  app:errorTextAppearance.

Comment: Please show what have you tried completely, then it'll be easy to find out solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a `SpannableString` to set the font:

```
SpannableString s = new SpannableString(errorString);
s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(font), 0, s.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
mPasswordView.setError(s);
```

A custom `Span` class that has a specific `Typeface` set:

```
public class TypefaceSpan extends MetricAffectingSpan {
    private Typeface mTypeface;
    public TypefaceSpan(Typeface typeface) {
        mTypeface = typeface;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint p) {
        p.setTypeface(mTypeface);
        p.setFlags(p.getFlags() | Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint tp) {
        tp.setTypeface(mTypeface);
        tp.setFlags(tp.getFlags() | Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it really works! I wasted whole day thinking that a new font haven't applied. Then I downloaded a new font (like https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Pacifico) and noticed it really changed.

Answer (score 1):

Another method if you like it, you can set **Error color or Font** both

```
public static void setErrorTextColor(TextInputLayout textInputLayout, int color, Typeface font) {
  try {
    Field fErrorView = TextInputLayout.class.getDeclaredField("mErrorView");
    fErrorView.setAccessible(true);
    TextView mErrorView = (TextView) fErrorView.get(textInputLayout);
    Field fCurTextColor = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mCurTextColor");
    fCurTextColor.setAccessible(true);
    fCurTextColor.set(mErrorView, color);
    mErrorView.setTypeface(font);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: Now throws error: "java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field mErrorView in class Lcom/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout;".